error "401" unauthorized_client while requesting for refresh and access token using authorization code
I am trying to get refresh token and access token from OAuth2 using the authorization code. But I am repeatedly getting unauthorized_client error as response. I have configured the consent screen and created OAuth credentials as per the documentation. I am able to get the response for a different account using the same cURL command in postman.
Sending request to this link : https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
"code": "<authorization_code>",
    "client_id": "<client_id>",
    "client_secret": "<client_secret>",
    "redirect_uri": "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code"

This is the response I am getting. I have checked the credentials multiple times, everything is fine.
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "Unauthorized"

